# unable to pass studentid from java to mysql in where clause

Tags: java, mysql

In my below program i want to update student information in `mysql` passing the values from user input. The inputs are studentid and firstname.

The sql query used is

```
String update = "UPDATE `student_db`.`studentinfo` SET `Student_LastName`='"+firstname+"' WHERE `Student_ID`= '"+studentid+"' ";
```

Executing the above program dosnt works, but the same query if i hard code the studentid value in query it works which i dont want...

Example : `String update = "UPDATE`student_db`.`studentinfo`SET`Student_LastName`='"+firstname+"' WHERE`Student_ID`= '3' ";`

I want where clause to take input from user, update in query and execute.

```
public static void firstname() {
            Scanner studentid= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your Studentid");
            studentid.nextLine();

                    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);

                    System.out.println("Please enter your first name:"); 

                        while(!name.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+")){

                            System.out.println("Please re-enter your name, use alphabets only");
                            System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");
                            name.nextLine();

                        }
                        String firstname=name.nextLine();   
                        System.out.println("Your Updated firstname is " + firstname);

                        //Connection to db
                        try{
                        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/student_db","root","admin");
                        Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
                        String update = "UPDATE `student_db`.`studentinfo` SET `Student_LastName`='"+firstname+"' WHERE `Student_ID`= '"+studentid+"' ";
                        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(update);
                        int rs= stmt.executeUpdate(update);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            System.err.println(e);
                        }
                }           

    enter code here
```

Comment: Any error or exception are you getting?

Comment: im not getting any error, the program executes and in database there are no updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static void firstname() {

```
        System.out.println("Please enter your Studentid");

        Scanner studentid= new Scanner(System.in);

        int stdnumber = studentid.nextInt();

        studentid.nextLine();

        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your first name:"); 

    while(!name.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+")){  
        System.out.println("Please re-enter your name, use alphabets only");
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");
        name.nextLine();                        
        }

    String firstname=name.nextLine();   

    System.out.println("Your Updated firstname is " + firstname);

    //Connection to db
    try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/student_db","root","admin");

        Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

        String update = "UPDATE `student_db`.`studentinfo` SET `Student_FirstName`='"+firstname+"' WHERE `Student_ID`='"+stdnumber+"' ";

        int rs= stmt.executeUpdate(update);

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all debug your application and  check your sql query in logs Is it working ?

After that read documentation for PreparedStatement from here [Read here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
String update = "UPDATE `student_db`.`studentinfo` SET `Student_LastName`=? WHERE `Student_ID`= ? ";
PreparedStatement stmt= con.prepareStatement(update);
stmt.setString(1, firstName); 
stmt.setString(2, studentId);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use PreparedStatement (with parameterized value).

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE studentinfo SET   Student_LastName=? WHERE Student_ID= ?");
    stmt.setString(1, firstName);  //setString - depend on type of value in database
    stmt.setString(2, studentId);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
```

As you see I've changed your SQL. I've replaced concatenated parameters to parameterized query (?).

You have many mistakes in code. I've rewrite your code to

```
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your Studentid");
    String studentId = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");

    while(!scanner.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+")){
        System.out.println("Please re-enter your name, use alphabets only");
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
    String firstName = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: i stil have issue with using preparedstatments for studentid it says "The method setString(int, String) in the type prepared statment is not applicapable for argument(string,scanner)"

Comment: Check your value. Second argument is Scanner - wrong type. You need extract value from scanner ({scannerObject}.nextLine()).

Comment: `Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your Studentid");
String studentId = scanner.nextLine();`

Comment: i have updates stil it dosnt work as where clause input is a string... there are no updates in mysql database.

Comment: Are you can use debug? It's simple to check your problem. I think some variables have wrong value. You can see it in debug.